# Python Check if Key/Value exists in JSON output

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have a JSON output and I want to create an IF statement so if it contains the value I am looking for the do something ELSE do something else.

JSON Blob 1

```
[
   {
      "domain":"www.slatergordon.co.uk",
      "displayed_link":"https://www.slatergordon.co.uk/",
      "description":"We Work With Thousands Of People Across The UK In All Areas Of Personal Legal Services. Regardless Of How You Have Been Injured Through Negligence We're Here To Help You. Personal Injury Experts.",
      "position":1,
      "block_position":"top",
      "title":"Car Claims Solicitors - No Win No Fee Solicitors - SlaterGordon.co.uk",
      "link":"https://www.slatergordon.co.uk/personal-injury-claim/road-traffic-accidents-solicitors/",
      "tracking_link":"https://www.google.co.uk/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwj8-NSdjLDwAhXBEH0KHRYwA1MYABABGgJwdg&sig=AOD64_3u1ct0jmXAnvemxFHh_tfK5UK8Xg&q&adurl"
   },
   {
      "is_phone_ad":true,
      "phone_number":"0333 358 0496",
      "domain":"www.accident-claimsline.co.uk",
      "displayed_link":"http://www.accident-claimsline.co.uk/",
      "description":"Car Insurance Claims Advice - Car Accident Claims Helpline",
      "sitelinks":[
         {
            "title":"Replacement Vehicle Hire",
            "tracking_link":"https://www.google.co.uk/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwj8-NSdjLDwAhXBEH0KHRYwA1MYABALGgJwdg&ae=2&sig=AOD64_20YjAoyMY_c6XVTnBU1vQAD2tDTA&q=&ved=2ahUKEwjvlM-djLDwAhVmJzQIHSZHDLEQvrcBegQIBRAM&adurl="
         },
         {
            "title":"Request a Call Back",
            "tracking_link":"https://www.google.co.uk/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwj8-NSdjLDwAhXBEH0KHRYwA1MYABAOGgJwdg&ae=2&sig=AOD64_36-Pd831AXrPbh1yvUyTbhXH2irg&q=&ved=2ahUKEwjvlM-djLDwAhVmJzQIHSZHDLEQvrcBegQIBRAN&adurl="
         }
      ],
      "position":6,
      "block_position":"bottom",
      "title":"Car Insurance Claims Advice - Car Accident Claims Helpline",
      "link":"http://www.accident-claimsline.co.uk/",
      "tracking_link":"https://www.google.co.uk/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwj8-NSdjLDwAhXBEH0KHRYwA1MYABAGGgJwdg&ae=2&sig=AOD64_09pMtWxFo9s8c1dL16NJo5ThOlrg&q&adurl"
   }
]
```

JSON Blob 2

```
JSON

[
   {
      "domain":"www.slatergordon.co.uk",
      "displayed_link":"https://www.slatergordon.co.uk/",
      "description":"We Work With Thousands Of People Across The UK In All Areas Of Personal Legal Services. Regardless Of How You Have Been Injured Through Negligence We're Here To Help You. Personal Injury Experts.",
      "position":1,
      "block_position":"top",
      "title":"Car Claims Solicitors - No Win No Fee Solicitors - SlaterGordon.co.uk",
      "link":"https://www.slatergordon.co.uk/personal-injury-claim/road-traffic-accidents-solicitors/",
      "tracking_link":"https://www.google.co.uk/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwj8-NSdjLDwAhXBEH0KHRYwA1MYABABGgJwdg&sig=AOD64_3u1ct0jmXAnvemxFHh_tfK5UK8Xg&q&adurl"
   },
   {
      "is_phone_ad":true,
      "phone_number":"0333 358 0496",
      "domain":"www.accident-claimsline.co.uk",
      "displayed_link":"http://www.accident-claimsline.co.uk/",
      "description":"Car Insurance Claims Advice - Car Accident Claims Helpline",
      "sitelinks":[
         {
            "title":"Replacement Vehicle Hire",
            "tracking_link":"https://www.google.co.uk/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwj8-NSdjLDwAhXBEH0KHRYwA1MYABALGgJwdg&ae=2&sig=AOD64_20YjAoyMY_c6XVTnBU1vQAD2tDTA&q=&ved=2ahUKEwjvlM-djLDwAhVmJzQIHSZHDLEQvrcBegQIBRAM&adurl="
         },
         {
            "title":"Request a Call Back",
            "tracking_link":"https://www.google.co.uk/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwj8-NSdjLDwAhXBEH0KHRYwA1MYABAOGgJwdg&ae=2&sig=AOD64_36-Pd831AXrPbh1yvUyTbhXH2irg&q=&ved=2ahUKEwjvlM-djLDwAhVmJzQIHSZHDLEQvrcBegQIBRAN&adurl="
         }
      ],
      "position":6,
      "block_position":"top",
      "title":"Car Insurance Claims Advice - Car Accident Claims Helpline",
      "link":"http://www.accident-claimsline.co.uk/",
      "tracking_link":"https://www.google.co.uk/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwj8-NSdjLDwAhXBEH0KHRYwA1MYABAGGgJwdg&ae=2&sig=AOD64_09pMtWxFo9s8c1dL16NJo5ThOlrg&q&adurl"
   }
]
```

Desired Output

```
if "block_position":"bottom" in JSONBlob:
    do something
else:
    do something else
```

but I cant seem to get it to trigger for me. I want it to search through the entire output and if it contains that key/value do something and if it doesnt contain it do something else.

Blob 1 would go down the IF path

Blob 2 would go down the else path

Comment: `Is there anything I am missing?` - You are missing the code to iterate/search through the list of dicts.  Please provide a [mre].

Comment: You seem to be missing that you need to parse the JSON content, getting a Python object ou of it. Based on this object, you can test it, python-style (what you've done is not a valid test). What of these have you tried so far?

Comment: -1 : this question is not showing any actual python code. I will reconsider once you either clarify what you have done, or at least remove the 'python' tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem you have here is that the JSON output is a list/array with two objects inside. As you can have the `block_position` key in ***[any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)*** of the inner objects, you could do something like this:

```
if any([obj.get('block_position') == 'bottom' for obj in JSONBlob]):
    print('I do something')
else:
    print('I do somehting else')
```

**EDIT 1:** OK, I think I got your point. You only need to do something for **each object** with `block_position` set to `bottom`. Then the following should do it:

```
for obj in JSONBlob:
    if obj.get('block_position') == 'bottom':
        print('I do something with the object')
    else:
        print('I do something else with the object')
```

**EDIT 2:** As spoken in the post, if you only want to do something with the objects with `block_position` set as `bottom`, you can suppress the `else` clause as follows:

```
for obj in JSONBlob:
    if obj.get('block_position') == 'bottom':
        print('I do something with the object')
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. this works for me however, I need it to only look for 1 match. this will "do something" everytime there is a match inside of the blob and will also so the else path because block_position can sometimes be "top"

Comment: Sorry, I might not have correctly understood you but, what do you exactly need then? Store, for example, in a list, all the objects that have set `block_position` to `bottom`? I thought you only needed to detect if there was an object or not.

Comment: So I have a list of results. If one of those results has a match I want it to move on but if it does not contain block_position to bottom then do something else. for example, the JSONBlob above i would want it to go down the DO SOMETHING path as it has a bottom in it at the moment it would look at it and go down both paths

Comment: I think I understand now, I made an edit on the post. Is it now what you want?

Comment: It still seems that if the blob contains a bottom and something else (which could be the case) its taking both routes :/ ideally i would like it to only do the 1 route

Comment: Well there is no problem about that, you should only pick then the `if` part and forget about the `else` one, right? I mean, you only want the 'DO SOMETHING' part, so avoid adding an `else` clause and that should be it! I edited the post again to see if this matches your requirements.

Comment: that would work but if i contains a bottom i need to do something with it but if it doesn't contain a bottom i need to do something else with it so what can i do in this instance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231940/discussion-between-sherlock-bourne-and-will).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) library. Its a query language for JSON.
Basic jmespath expression for your case would be [?block_position==`bottom`]. This will filter out the specific node for you.
I tried it online [here](https://jmespath.org/) with data provided by you.
If you are looking for more nested node you will only have to alter your expression to search that specific node.

[image]